# Python Logistic regression and future samples

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I'm learning Logistic regression in Python and have managed to fit a model to my existing data (stock market data), and the predictions produce a nice result.

But I do not know how to convert that predictive model in a way I can apply it to future data. Ie is there a y=ax+b algo I can use to input future samples? How do I use the 'model'? How does one use the prediction for subsequent data? Or am I off track here - is Logistic regression not applied in this manner?

Comment: "...and the predictions produce a nice result." How are you getting those predictions?

Comment: I think I may understand the process now - Bill, I separated the sample into train and test, with the 'nice result' being the results indicated by the confusion matrix on the test sample. However I think if I were to get some new data and reference that data in the `newdata = logmodel.predict(new_data)`, then 'newdata' should contain the predictions for that new data.

Answer (score 0):

When you train the Logistic Regression, you learn the parameters `a` and `b` in `y = ax + b`. So, after training, `a` and `b` are known and can be used to solve the equation `y = ax + b`.

I don't know what exact Python packages you did use to train your model and how many classes you have, but if it would be, let's say, `numpy` and `2 classes`, the prediction function could look like this:

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(z):
    """
    Compute the sigmoid of z.

    Arguments:
    z: a scalar or numpy array

    Return:
    s: sigmoid(z)
    """

    s = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

    return s

def predict(w, b, X):
     '''
     Predict whether the label is 0 or 1 using learned logistic 
     regression parameters (w, b).

     Arguments:
     w: weights
     b: bias
     X: data to predict

    Returns:
    Y_pred: a numpy array (vector) containing all predictions (0/1) 
    for the examples in X
    '''

    m = X.shape[1] # number of instances in X
    Y_pred = np.zeros((1,m))
    w = w.reshape(X.shape[0], 1)

    # Apply the same activation function which you applied during 
    # training, in this case it is a sigmoid 
    A = sigmoid(np.dot(w.T, X) + b)


    for i in range(A.shape[1]):

        # Convert probabilities A[0,i] to actual predictions p[0,i]
        if A[0, i] > 0.5:
            Y_pred[0, i] = 1
        else:
            Y_pred[0, i] = 0

        return Y_pred
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using the scikit learn package, and I have 29 parameters. I have a 'predictions' array, but I don't see any array throughout the process that would contain the parameters.